# Package (Windows) of Metahuman scene + Nvidia Omniverse (a2f) not working

Tags: nvidia, unreal-engine5, omniverse

Please advise how to properly package UE 5.2.1 project for Windows, where only Metahuman is used?
It results in no errors, but when it's launched I observe short-timed black screen and then program crashes/exits. Only Metahuman plugin is enabled.

I need to package a Metahuman project with Nvidia Audio2Face (Omniverse Livelink) plugin enabled so that a ready-made project could use it, but when a2f plugin is enabled I see the error in log:

```
"Expecting to find a type to be declared in a module rules named ‘OmniverseAudioMixer’ in UE5Rules"
```

Settings are configured for Runtime.

Any possible solution for this?